# center top navigation horizontally while leaving logo on the left and language selection in the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to horizontally align my menu in the center while aligning logo to the left and language selection to the right. what I can't figure out at all is how to hold the same proportions on resize. I have tried a lot of suggestions but didn't find any that would suit my navigation bar.
Heres what I am trying:

**CSS:**

```
.nav-bar img {
    float: left;
}
.nav-bar {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
}
.nav-bar ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#menu {
  float: left;
}

#languages {
  float: right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="container">

    <img id="logo" src="image.svg">

    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="lang-bar">
      <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fr</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align:center` for the container, make the `ul` inline-blocks and position the logo and the language menu absolutely at the top left and top right:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
}

#container ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#lang-bar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <img id="logo" src="image.svg">

  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul id="lang-bar">
    <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fr</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` on the parent, and you could use `justify-content: space-between` to separate the 3 flex children, but that won't truly center the logo. Instead I would enable `flex-grow: 1` with `flex-basis: 0` on the flex children (or `flex: 1 0 0;` for short) so they occupy an equal amount of space, then align the content in the flex children appropriately. You can use `align-items: center` on the main container to center everything vertically, too, if you want.

```css
#container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#container > * {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

#lang-bar {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}


#logo {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
 
#menu {
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
  margin: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="flex">
  <div class="logoContainer">
    <img id="logo" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  </div>
  <ul id="menu" class="flex">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="lang-bar" class="flex">
    <li><a href="#">En</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fr</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```